# Chrome extension not resizing to original

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome-extension. This has a login field and an error message can be displayed whenever invalid credentials were entered. After the error message disappears, the window does not resize back to its original.

Before the error message:

[image: Before login]

The error message:

[image: Error message]

After the error message:

[image: After error message]

How do I make sure the window resizes back to the original height after the message is gone?

```
<body>
    <div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
        <div class="column">
            <div id="authView">
                <h2 class="ui teal header">
                <div class="content" style="margin-top:0.5em;">Log in</div>
                </h2>
                <form class="ui large form" id="login-form">
                    <div class="ui segment">
                        <div id="login-error" class="ui hidden negative message">
                            <p>Invalid username or password. Please try again</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="ui left icon input">
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="ui left icon input">
                                <i class="lock icon"></i>
                                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input class="ui fluid large teal submit button" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="mainView" style="display:none;">
                <h2 class="ui teal header" style="margin-top:0.5em;">
                    <div class="content">Listening for calls...</div>
                </h2>
                <form class="ui large form" id="call-form">
                    <div class="ui segment">
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="ui left icon input" id="callDiv">
                                <i class"icon call"></i>
                                <input type="text" id="destNumber" placeholder="Number to call" autofocus />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input class="ui fluid large teal submit button" value="Call" type="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <button class="ui negative button" id="sign-out">
                        <i class="icon sign out"></i>
                        Sign out
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The error message is shown using a simple function:

```
function showLoginError(message, duration = 5000) {
    $('#login-error').html(message);
    $('#login-error').removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#login-error').addClass('hidden');
    }, duration);
}
```

I'm using Semantic-UI btw, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already - try explicitly stating the height to be auto for the element that isn't resizing back.

I know I've run into issues where if I don't state that explicitly, the height defines itself when an event happens (even if there's no inline style) and I run into issues.

Comment: The thing that doesn't seem to be resizing back to the origin, is the body. However setting this to `height: auto;` messes it up even more, showing a long stretched view.

Comment: Is it displaying wrong even at first - before the error? Or after the error? If it's even at first, then maybe having a look at the code can help trouble shoot more. If it's only after the errors, then I'm led to believe that whatever container or div the errors arrive in have some sort of height attached to them that is staying and pushing the rest of the body down with it.

Comment: Added the html/js